# Why can't add semicolon at the last statement in js' for loop?

Tags: javascript, for-loop

The js's `for loop` formal format is as below:

```
for (statement 1; statement 2; statement 3) {
  code block to be executed
}
```

WHy can't add a semicolon at the end of `statement 3` ?

```
for (statement 1; statement 2; statement 3;) {
  code block to be executed
}
```

Please tell me the logic instead of rule.

Comment: Because the syntax is defined as `for (;;)`, not `for (;;;)`…

Comment: But there is no logic here, it *is* the rule (of the for syntax, in this case). The semi-colon is acting as a separator here, not an "end of statement" character. Your "statement 2" for instance isn't a statement but an expression.

Comment: The semi-colon is a delimiter here.  In the same way you would do `function x(a, b, c)` rather than `function x(a, b, c,)`

Answer (score 3):

These aren't statement terminators like the usual `;`, they're a specific part of the [`for` syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for).

As in this:

```
for (let i = 0; i < 10; ++i) { ... }
```

Is quite different from this:

```
let i = 0;
i < 10;
++i;
```

This is all to do with how the language is parsed and what meaning each symbol has in any given context. Sometimes `;` is a statement terminator, but you're probably aware that is not always the case:

```
let semicolon = ";";
```

There's two semicolons there, and only one is a statement terminator. One is part of a string. Likewise those inside the `for` are special.

If you look at the formal definition on MDN you can see `for` defined as:

```
for ( init_clause ; cond_expression ; iteration_expression ) loop_statement
```

Where each of those terms, `init_clause`, `cond_expression` and `iteration_expression` are specific expressions allowed there, and their specific function is defined below that.

The specific syntax of the `for` statement is inherited from [the C version of same](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/for).

It's entirely possible that JavaScript could have chosen some other symbol here, like `#`, and it would work the same way, but that would make JavaScript feel a bit odd for those familiar with C or other C-inspired languages with precisely the same structure like C++ and Java.

Answer (score 1):

well the syntax for the for loop is this

```
for(;;)
{ 
//anything
}
```

ex :

```
for(x=0;x<5;x++)
{ 
console.log(x);
}
```